# Bluring behind something then drawing text?

Tags: c++, shaders, glsl, blur

I want to basically make a blur shader in glsl and use it like Windows 7 does for Windows. I want to for example draw something and then blur a rectangle, then draw text over it.

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of effect is known as a [Guassian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). It's a relatively common effect, so you can find information about the algorithm and even some sample shaders relatively easily: for example, [here](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/11/gaussian-blur-filter-shader/), [here](http://callumhay.blogspot.com/2010/09/gaussian-blur-shader-glsl.html) and [here](http://theinstructionlimit.com/?p=14) were the first three Google results that looked vaguely worthwhile.

The general idea is that you're going to have to render the scene you want blurred into a render target texture, then bind that texture for a second render phase during which you'll compute the blur effect.

To render *sharp* images on top of the blur (for example, your text), you can render the blurring phase into a render target texture as well, and bind that texture for the final pass where you'd render your text over the scene.

You may also want to look for [discussion of GPU post-processing systems](http://poisonforthemind.blogspot.com/2009/12/gpu-post-processing.html) to get a feel for how you might architect you render pipeline to be generally scalable to these sorts of multi-phase effects.